# Apache Artemis - Route messages by addresses with multiple queues

Tags: apache-camel, wildfly, activemq-artemis

I have this scenario:

```
ADDRESS1:
   -ADDRESS1.QUEUE1
   -ADDRESS1.QUEUE2

ADDRESS2:
   -ADDRESS2.QUEUE1
   -ADDRESS2.QUEUE2
```

Two addresses with multiple anycast queues. I need to route messages to a specify queue into the address.

Example:

```
Messages on ADDRESS1::ADDRESS1.QUEUE1 goes to -> ADDRESS2::ADDRESS2.QUEUE1 
Messages on ADDRESS1::ADDRESS1.QUEUE2 goes to -> ADDRESS2::ADDRESS2.QUEUE2
```

This is my code:

```
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("admin", "admin", "tcp://0.0.0.0:61616");

    context.addComponent("artemis", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(factory));

    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("artemis:ADDRESS1::ADDRESS1.QUEUE1")
            .log("${body}")
            .to("artemis:ADDRESS2::ADDRESS2.QUEUE1");
        }
    });

    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("artemis:ADDRESS1::ADDRESS1.QUEUE2")
            .log("${body}")
            .to("artemis:ADDRESS2::ADDRESS2.QUEUE2");
        }
    });
```

With this code I'm able only to consume messages from a specific queue. But ".to" doesn't work.
Is there any way to do that?

I need to do that because I have many applications that are consumers, so I want to use address to separate the queues "by application".

Like this:

```
APP1
   QUEUE1
   QUEUE2
   QUEUE3
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a solution, but I don't know if is the best one.

I added filters on my destination queues:

```
    ADDRESS2:
       -ADDRESS2.QUEUE1 - Filter -> DESTIONATION = 'QUEUE1' 
       -ADDRESS2.QUEUE2 - Filter -> DESTIONATION = 'QUEUE2'
```

And when I route the message with camel, I set a Header with a value, and .to() I set only the Address name:

```
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("artemis:ADDRESS1::ADDRESS1.QUEUE1")
            .log("${body}")
            .setHeader("DESTINATION", constant("QUEUE1"))
            .to("artemis:ADDRESS2");
        }
    });

    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("artemis:ADDRESS1::ADDRESS1.QUEUE1")
            .log("${body}")
            .setHeader("DESTINATION", constant("QUEUE2"))
            .to("artemis:ADDRESS2");
        }
    });
```

This works, but as I said, I don't know if is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the "replyTo" on producer endpoints:

```
.to("artemis:ADDRESS2::ADDRESS2.QUEUE1?disableReplyTo=true")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply. I got the same behavior with this parameter :(